# How to cut a string at a specific point?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

So, I have a vast quantity of `NSString`s and my problem is I need to cut them into smaller strings at a specific point. This may sound complicated but what I need basically is this:

```
NSString *test =" blah blah blah - goo goo goo.";
NSString *str1 = "blah blah blah ";
NSString *str2 = "goo goo goo";
```

How do I code for when there's a hyphen for the string to just cut off there. Is there a way to do this? I found ways to cut of the string after a certain amount of letters but I need it at the hyphen every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *arr = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this many ways. Two answers above show a few approaches. Many Objective-C  solutions will include NSRange usage. You could also do more flexible things with NSScanner or NSRegularExpression. 
There is not going to be one right answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *cutString = [text substringFromIndex:3];
cutString = [text substringToIndex:5];
cutString = [text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 5)];
```